# Creating Grouped features in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sample records for a particular trialid from a table like below:

```
Personid    Trial   orgid   Orgtypeid   
90  106 72001   4                       
682 106 188787  4                       
717 106 187761  4                       
830 106 64776   4                       
845 106 71795   3                       
1130    106 215441  22                      
1199    106 25148   22                      
1488    106 84256   4                       
1656    106 31456   22                      
2427    106 71864   22                      
2535    106 40687   3                       
2558    106 93306   4                       
2792    106 114207  18                      
3105    106 13967   22                      
3267    106 22634   18                      
3352    106     22                      
3516    106 9847    12                      
3981    106 2341    4                       
3993    106 126593  3                       
4025    106 29789   4                       
4395    106 75068   3                       
4433    106 17622   3                       
4662    106 45286   4                       
4887    106 18350   22                      
5272    106 46979   18                      
5381    106 82499   3                       
5518    106 72958   3                       
5593    106 93363   3                       
5634    106 49553   18                      
5686    106 82504   22                      
6036    106 79250   3                       
6047    106 46228   4                       
6260    106 52492   4                       
6365    106 31196   3                       
6443    106 1980    4                       
6492    106 72940   3                       
6539    106 45287   4                       
6641    106 124592  4                       
6659    106 184510  4                       
6768    106 3950    4                       
7172    106 93065   22                      
7183    106 71916   4                       
7285    106 181783  22                      
8030    106 31044   4                       
8071    106 84539   22                      
8350    106 73263   4                       
8395    106 14974   4                       
8612    106 33084   12                      
8785    106 52983   4                       
8837    106 18335   4                       
8852    106 182042  3                       
8902    106 191396  3                       
8909    106 44678   12                      
8982    106     19                      
9318    106 149996  4                       
9538    106 31827   4                       
9570    106 85130   4                       
10028   106 159192  18                      
10105   106 38784   4                       
10226   106 80419   4                       
10459   106 79827   22                      
10518   106 71836   12                      
10733   106 71876   4                       
10843   106 78913   4                       
10853   106 140548  22                      
10880   106 71923   4                       
11301   106 72020   4                       
11522   106 33167   3                       
11595   106 71624   22                      
11699   106 91917   4                       
11714   106 93150   3                       
12200   106 34207   4                       
12226   106 71649   4                       
12308   106 136005  4                       
12832   106 71841   4                       
13468   106 71580   4                       
13745   106 92433   4                       
13907   106 164068  3                       
13935   106 39943   3                       
14122   106 130995  3                       
14146   106 101833  18                      
14520   106 38050   4                       
14542   106 39616   4                       
14560   106 85695   3                       
14712   106 95460   4                       
14806   106 30621   22                      
15479   106 72778   4                       
15549   106 130557  3                       
15790   106 39652   4                       
15982   106 52193   3                       
16046   106 62592   4                       
16064   106 75808   18                      
16268   106 51957   12                      
16908   106 78731   4                       
17198   106 53941   3                       
17248   106 44436   18                      
17830   106 80244   4                       
18585   106 396 22                      
18621   106 77528   4                       
18723   106 35721   22                      
19112   106 4928    4                       
19413   106 172057  3                       
19729   106 10096   3                       
19772   106 181063  3                       
19774   106 9858    4                       
19849   106 213470  4                       
19880   106 184341  4                       
20051   106 10388   3                       
20330   106 964 22                      
20337   106 162349  4                       
20574   106 216255  4                       
20619   106 42352   4                       
20666   106 10830   4                       
20746   106 19308   3                       
21123   106 114302  22                      
21190   106 41878   22                      
21261   106 33084   4                       
21264   106 84340   3                       
21651   106 52210   4                       
21682   106 167293  3                       
21775   106 80419   4                       
21930   106 154783  4                       
22017   106 78213   12                      
22026   106 11815   4                       
22924   106 57492   4                       
23149   106 46928   4                       
23775   106 141288  22                      
23831   106 162443  3                       
24887   106 9831    3                       
25279   106 71598   3                       
25357   106 75448   22                      
25468   106 98249   4                       
25651   106     4                       
25807   106 93306   4                       
26318   106 44212   22                      
26347   106 1143    3                       
26551   106 53264   3                       
27414   106     18                      
27424   106 126205  4                       
27556   106 147586  3                       
27582   106 145836  3                       
27774   106 7471    3                       
28004   106 119457  22                      
28684   106 3058    22                      
28686   106 16625   3                       
30026   106 144890  3                       
30031   106 32934   3                       
30035   106 40801   4                       
30039   106 177508  22                      
30238   106 72646   4                       
30430   106 82810   4                       
30471   106 46299   3                       
30944   106 184183  4                       
31482   106 42368   4                       
32296   106 196312  4                       
33801   106 13704   3                       
34903   106 347 3                       
35332   106 206713  3                       
36386   106 71612   4                       
38208   106 36293   3                       
38749   106 77258   18                      
38827   106 72071   4                       
39561   106 140106  4                       
39722   106 46471   3                       
39849   106 125641  18                      
40599   106 53061   4                       
42614   106 28447   18                      
42691   106 183045  22                      
43152   106 73580   19                      
43638   106 10321   3                       
47110   106 29789   4                       
47112   106 98308   4                       
48608   106 45292   4                       
48856   106 6700    4                       
48947   106 185045  3                       
48948   106 73515   4                       
49642   106 164536  4                       
49735   106 78342   4                       
50352   106 75696   12                      
50353   106 33699   4                       
51985   106 82265   12                      
52671   106 142891  4                       
52777   106 84193   22                      
52778   106 18406   3                       
53561   106 11674   3                       
53563   106 81427   4                       
53564   106 28320   4                       
54409   106 27689   4                       
54411   106 33761   3                       
54412   106 11695   22                      
54470   106 39649   4                       
54858   106 91972   22                      
55129   106 73820   4                       
55130   106 11815   22                      
55566   106 203178  9                       
55569   106 157517  4                       
55570   106 124075  4                       
56871   106 63954   3                       
57726   106 13484   3                       
60131   106 75956   3                       
61074   106 21444   3                       
61335   106 24403   4                       
63049   106 42236   3                       
65447   106 43170   22                      
65450   106 39728   22                      
65453   106 22211   22                      
65454   106 46546   3                       
67232   106 27052   18                      
68494   106 47882   3                       
68495   106 816 22                      
68936   106 106618  22                      
70192   106 173595  3                       
70193   106 115501  22                      
70197   106 34341   3                       
72606   106 18418   4                       
73104   106 144374  19                      
73685   106 51520   22                      
74397   106 102254  3                       
76808   106 44391   18                      
81334   106 34705   4                       
82894   106 45223   4                       
89882   106 154988  3                       
93661   106 51278   4                       
100468  106     4                       
100694  106 45358   18                      
100722  106     22                      
100789  106     9                       
100853  106     3                       
101307  106 159932  12                      
101326  106 39675   3                       
103620  106 48956   3                       
103668  106 44771   22                      
104706  106 142662  4                       
105923  106 76883   10                      
105961  106 75959   10                      
106555  106 72111   10                      
112996  106 71618   10                      
128637  106 138211  22                      
170771  106 117977  4                       
199749  106 72703   22                      
202961  106 32966   4                       
348476  106 49553   4                       
420379  106 21642   22                      
421422  106 24547   4
```

Here the personid is the id of the person. Trailid is the id we are looking at, orgid is the id of an organization, orgtypeid is the type of org.

Now what we want is for each group of trialid(this example only has one trailid but the base table has multiple trialids),I want to create 6 new variables as indicated below:

```
Non Academic_fraction_orgs  Academic_frac_orgs  Others_frac_orgs    Non Academic_fraction_ppl   Academic_frac_ppl   Others_frac_ppl
```

orgtypeid : 9, 18, 3 are grouped as Academic, while 4,22,17 are grouped as Non-Academic while remaining are grouped as Others. Now we need the above variables with following values:

```
Non Academic_fraction_orgs: Total  orgids in Non-Academic in that trialid/Total Orgids in that trialid

Academic_fraction_orgs: Total  orgids in Academic in that trialid/Total Orgids in that trailed

Others_frac_orgs: Total  orgids in Other in that trialid/Total Orgids in that trailed

Non Academic_fraction_ppl: Total  distinct Personid in Non-Academic in that trialid/Total Orgids in that trailed

Academic_fraction_ppl: Total  distinct Personid in Academic in that trialid/Total Orgids in that trailed
```

and so on..

How to get this done in sql.

EDIT:

strorganizationtype is the string of respective orgtypeid.

```
select trialid, count(CASE WHEN strorganizationtype in ('Academic Institution - office','Academic Institution - research facility',
 'Academic Hospital / Clinic') 
 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /(count(*)*1.0) as Academic_frac_orgs,

 count(CASE WHEN strorganizationtype in ('Medical Practice','Clinical Trial Center',
 'Rehabilitation/Extended Care Facility','Non-academic Hospital / Clinic')
 THEN 1 Else 0 END)/(count(*)*1.0) as Non_Academic_fraction_orgs,

 count(CASE WHEN strorganizationtype in ('Company','Other')
 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/(count(*)*1.0) as Other_fraction_orgs
from table
group by trailid
order by trialid
```

The problem is that count(CASE WHEN strorganizationtype in ('Company','Other')
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) is counting all records for that trial and not those which belong to this particular case statement. I need a variable which is a fraction of records which belong to this group of orgs by total orgs which belong to that group.

Comment: You can use **group by**  trialid, **case when** for getting different columns, with **count** or **sum**.

Comment: Yeah I am having trouble with case statement with count and sum.Please advise

Comment: should be like **sum(case when orgtypeid in (9, 8, 3) then 1 else 0 end)** or **count(case when orgtypeid in (9, 8, 3) then 1 else null end)**

Comment: you can update your question with your existing sql, the question would be more clear then.

Comment: Show the query that you are working on or a fiddle in order to detect whats your problem.

Comment: Postgres sql. 

Here is the query I am writing. Check edit

Comment: Please check the edit and the comments

Comment: There are some lines in your sample data missing the orgid